# GAMS- manipulating expression within a loop

Tags: gams-math

I have a matrix, of dimension, i rows and j columns, a specific element of which is called x(i,j), where say i are plants, and j are markets. In standard GAMS notation:

```
Sets
     i   canning plants   / seattle, san-diego /
     j   markets          / new-york, chicago, topeka / ;
```

Now, I also wish to create a loop, over time- for 5 periods. Essentially, say I define

Set t time period

```
 /period1
  period2
  period3
  period4
  period5

            / ;
```

Parameters

```
time(t)
/ period1 1,
  period2 2,
  period3 3,
  period4 4,
  period5 5
               / ;
```

Basically, I want to re-run this loop, which contains a bunch of other commands, but I wish to re-define this matrix from period 2 onwards, to look like this:

```
x("seattle",j)=x("seattle",j)+s("new-york",j)
x("new-york",j)=0'
```

Essentially, within the loop, I want the matrix x(i,j) to look different after period 2, wherein the column x("seattle",j) is replaced with the erstwhile x("seattle",j)+s("new-york",j)  and the column x("new-york",j) is set to 0.

The loop would start like :

```
loop
(t,
...

Option reslim = 20000 ;

option nlp = conopt3 ;

solve example using NLP maximizing VARIABLE ;

  )  ;
```

I am not sure how to keep redefining this matrix within the loop, for each period>2.

**Please note:** After period 2, the matrix looks the same. The change only happens once (i.e., the matrix elements do not keep looping from the previous period, but just switch **once** , at the end of period 2, and then stay constant thereafter.

Any help on this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a $ condition to make this change in the loop for `period2` only, like this:

```
x("seattle",j)$sameAs(t,'period2')=x("seattle",j)+s("new-york",j);
```

Comment: Sorry- just a follow up. Say that I wish to make each element in the seattle column double relative to its previous period's value. Would it simply be: x("seattle",j)=2*x("seattle",j) ? Would GAMS recognize that this has to be repeated in each time period?

Comment: Yes. If you do it in a loop, it will be repeated for each iteration (unless you use a $ condition to exclude certain iterations). Just do "display x;" after the assignment to inspect the result of the operation in the lst file.